# start-stop-daemon does not write to nginx.pid file even though the file is present

Tags: nginx, start-stop-daemon

This may seem to be a repeated question but it is not. I found some articles on it where `start-stop-daemon` doesn't create a PID file. But in my case, I have already created the PID file. I execute this command on my server to start Nginx:

```
/mnt/nginx/logs/nginx.pid
start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile /mnt/nginx/logs/nginx.pid --exec /usr/local/sbin/nginx
```

The PID file is already present but still the `start-stop-daemon` doesn't write to the file. I even tried to use the `--make-pidfile` option but then the `start-stop-daemon` writes wrong pid to the file.

Answer (score 7):

The `--make-pidfile` option is required. The reason `start-stop-daemon` writes the "wrong pid" is that `nginx` forks. This is noted in the `start-stop-daemon` man page:

```
   -m, --make-pidfile
          Used when starting a program that does not create  its  own  pid
          file.  This  option  will make start-stop-daemon create the file
          referenced with --pidfile and place the pid into it just  before
          executing  the  process. Note, the file will not be removed when
          stopping the program.  NOTE: This feature may not  work  in  all
          cases.  Most  notably when the program being executed forks from
          its main process. Because of this, it  is  usually  only  useful
          when combined with the --background option.
```

(See the part re forking.)

You'll need to use a different solution, such as getting `nginx` to create its own pid file.

Comment: getting `nginx`to create its own file: this is describe there: http://wiki.nginx.org/CoreModule#pid. Basically you just have to add the pid directive to your nginx.conf file.